# Graph Isomorphism Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph Isomorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695173/graph-isomorphism)

Is there any good known heuristics for graph isomorphism. If some knows it please let me know also any good and easy  to understand algorithm for graph isomorphism.

Comment: Have you looked here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem?

Comment: Brendan McKay is the author of [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/), the state-of-the-art software for graph isomorphism. [This paper of his](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/pgi.pdf) explains some of the ideas.

Comment: Graph isomorphism can be checked by considering the two graphs as one graph and checking for symmetries/automorphisms. This can be done using [saucy](http://vlsicad.eecs.umich.edu/BK/SAUCY/) faster than using nauty.
Disclaimer: I am a co-author of saucy.

Answer (score 4):

The simple but efficient way for checking isomorphism between graphs that do not have pathologically uniform structure is to pick up a node invariant, calculate the value of the invariants for all the nodes, and then perform a (depth-first) search for the actual isomorphism only every pairing up nodes that have the same value for the node invariant. The idea of the node invariant that it's an object (usually number or sequence of numbers) that is calculated for nodes in a fashion that is totally independent of the representation of the graph; i.e. it's invariant under choosing a representation form.

For example, the number of neighbors a node has is an invariant, but the order in which your program iterates the neighbors of a node is not as that depends on representation (data structures).

Typically node invariants are calculated iteratively, e.g. this simple invariant I[n] where n is a node and I[n] is unsigned 32-bit integer:

```
for every node in graph:
  I[node] = count_neighbors(node)
for i = 0 .. N: # N is a constant, number of iterations
  for every node in graph:
    I'[node] = (I[node] << 13 | I[node] >> 19) ^ 0xff00ff00
    for every node' in neighbors(node):
      I'[node] += I[node']
  for every node in graph:
    I[node] = I'[node]
```

These types of invariants in practice distinguish most of the nodes from each other in non-uniform graphs, making the search phase quick in practice.

Comment: I got your idea for calculating the degree of the graph and i was also thinking some thing like that but once we have calculated the degree and reject the graph if one graph is not compatible to other then what after that what are the steps that you are explaining using DFS, Can you please elaborate it in detail and also what is the psuedocode is doing after line 4. Thanks

Comment: The pseudocode is calculating a hash value for the nodes, basically; this is the "invariant". The stuff with bit shifts and XORing is just a way to make the invariant to have less spurious collisions. The DFS search for the actual isomorphism search is missing, true... it would be another large bunch of pseudocode :)